# Помогите разрешить проблему с потоками

Tags: потоки-данных, java, многопоточность

Учусь программировать на джава, возникла проблема с задачей
/* Кроссворд

1. Дан двумерный массив, который содержит буквы английского алфавита в нижнем регистре.
2. Метод detectAllWords должен найти все слова из words в массиве crossword.
3. Элемент(startX, startY) должен соответствовать первой букве слова, элемент(endX, endX) - последней.
   text - это само слово, располагается между начальным и конечным элементами
4. Все слова есть в массиве.
5. Слова могут быть расположены горизонтально, вертикально и по диагонали как в нормальном, так и в обратном порядке.
6. Метод main не участвует в тестировании
   */

Логика моего решения, следующая для каждой степини свободы я создаю задачу для выполнения
потоком. Каждый отдельный поток, имеет дело только со своей степенью свободы. Далее я просто собираю результат работы потоков. НО в реальности возникает ошибка, сбой логики с потоками, сижу 2 дня и не могу определить место ошибки, догодываюсь что ошибка возникает при общем доступе потоков к ресурсу.

```
public class Solution {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] crossword = new int[][]{
            {'f', 'd', 'e', 'r', 'l', 'k'},
            {'u', 's', 'a', 'm', 'e', 'o'},
            {'l', 'n', 'g', 'r', 'o', 'v'},
            {'m', 'l', 'e', 'm', 'o', 'h'},
            {'p', 'o', 'e', 'e', 'j', 'j'}
    };
    List<Word> result = detectAllWords(crossword, "home");
    for (Word word : result)
        System.out.println(word);

    /*
```

Ожидаемый результат
home - (5, 3) - (2, 0)
same - (1, 1) - (4, 1)
         */
    }

```
public static List<Word> detectAllWords(int[][] crossword, String... words) {

    Crossword crosswordHelper = new Crossword(crossword, words);

    return crosswordHelper.doCrossword();
}

public static class Crossword
{

    private int[][] crossword;
    private String[] words;

    public Crossword(int[][] crossword, String[] words) {
        this.crossword = crossword;
        this.words = words;
    }

    public class Coordinate
    {
        private char letter;
        private int row;
        private int column;

        public Coordinate(char letter, int row, int column) {
            this.letter = letter;
            this.row = row;
            this.column = column;
        }

        public char getLetter()
        {
            return letter;
        }

        public int getRow()
        {
            return row;
        }

        public int getColumn()
        {
            return column;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return String.format("char=%c, row=%d, column=%d", letter, row, column);
        }

        public synchronized boolean inHorizontalLeftRange(Coordinate otherCoordinate) {

            return (otherCoordinate.getRow() == row && ((otherCoordinate.getColumn() - 1) == column)) ? true : false;

        }

        public synchronized boolean inHorizontalRightRange(Coordinate otherCoordinate) {

            return (otherCoordinate.getRow() == row && ((otherCoordinate.getColumn() + 1) == column)) ? true : false;

        }

        public synchronized boolean inVerticalUpRange(Coordinate otherCoordinate) {

            return (otherCoordinate.getColumn() == column && ((otherCoordinate.getRow() + 1) == row)) ? true : false;

        }

        public synchronized boolean inVerticalDownRange(Coordinate otherCoordinate) {

            return (otherCoordinate.getColumn() == column && ((otherCoordinate.getRow() - 1) == row)) ? true : false;

        }

        public synchronized boolean inDiagonalUpRightRange(Coordinate otherCoordinate) {

            return  ((row + 1) == otherCoordinate.getRow() && (column + 1) == otherCoordinate.getColumn()) ? true : false;

        }

        public synchronized boolean inDiagonalUpLeftRange(Coordinate otherCoordinate) {

            return ((row + 1) == otherCoordinate.getRow() && (column - 1) == otherCoordinate.getColumn()) ? true : false;

        }

        public synchronized boolean inDiagonalDownRightRange(Coordinate otherCoordinate) {

            return ((row - 1) == otherCoordinate.getRow() && (column + 1) == otherCoordinate.getColumn()) ? true : false;

        }

        public synchronized boolean inDiagonalDownLeftRange(Coordinate otherCoordinate) {

            return ((row - 1) == otherCoordinate.getRow() && (column - 1) == otherCoordinate.getColumn()) ? true : false;

        }

    }

    public class CoordinateFabric
    {
        private String word;

        public CoordinateFabric(String word) {
            this.word = word;
        }

        public List<Coordinate> findHeadLettersCoordinates() {

            List<Coordinate> result = new ArrayList<Coordinate>();

            char[] chars = word.toCharArray();
            char c = chars[0];

            for (int row = 0; row < crossword.length; row++) {
                for (int column = 0; column < crossword[row].length; column++) {
                    char tempChar = (char)crossword[row][column];

                    if (tempChar == c)
                        result.add(new Coordinate(c, row, column));
                }
            }

            return result;

        }

        public List<Coordinate> findAllLettersCoordinates() {

            List<Coordinate> result = new ArrayList<Coordinate>();
            char[] chars = word.toCharArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
                char c = chars[i];
                for (int row = 0; row < crossword.length; row++) {
                    for (int column = 0; column < crossword[row].length; column++) {
                        char tempChar = (char)crossword[row][column];

                        if (tempChar == c)
                            result.add(new Coordinate(c, row, column));

                    }
                }
            }

            return result;

        }

        public List<Word> startFabric() throws InterruptedException {

            // Думаю проблема к доступу к данному ресурсу но не уверен!
           final List<Word> listOfFoundWords = new ArrayList<>();

            List<String> directions = new ArrayList<>();
            directions.add("inHorizontalLeftRange");
            directions.add("inHorizontalRightRange");
            directions.add("inVerticalUpRange");
            directions.add("inVerticalDownRange");
            directions.add("inDiagonalUpRightRange");
            directions.add("inDiagonalUpLeftRange");
            directions.add("inDiagonalDownRightRange");
            directions.add("inDiagonalDownLeftRange");

            class DirectionThread extends Thread {

                private String methodName;
                private List<Coordinate> allCoordinates;
                private List<Coordinate> headCoordinates;

                public DirectionThread(String methodName, List<Coordinate> headCoordinates, List<Coordinate> allCoordinates) {
                    this.methodName = methodName;
                    this.headCoordinates = headCoordinates;
                    this.allCoordinates = allCoordinates;
                    start();
                }

                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    for (Coordinate head : headCoordinates) {

                        // BUILDING WORD FROM FIRST LETTER
                        List<Coordinate> container = new ArrayList<>();
                        container.add(head);

                        // THEN WE APPEND ANOTHER WORDS
                        for (Coordinate coordinate : allCoordinates) {
                            Coordinate nextCoordinate = container.get(container.size()-1);
                            try
                            {
                                Method method = Coordinate.class.getMethod(methodName.toString(), Coordinate.class);
                                boolean inRange = (boolean) method.invoke(nextCoordinate, coordinate);
                                if (inRange)
                                    container.add(coordinate);

                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if (container.size() == word.length())
                        {
                            Word resultWord = new Word(word);
                            Coordinate firstCoordinate = container.get(0);
                            resultWord.setStartPoint(firstCoordinate.getColumn() , firstCoordinate.getRow());

                            Coordinate lastCoordinate = container.get(container.size()-1);
                            resultWord.setEndPoint(lastCoordinate.getColumn(), lastCoordinate.getRow());

                            // Другое поведение программы, если расскоментировать код вывода на консоль,
                            // Не могу понят почему!
                            //System.out.println("one more word " + resultWord);
                            listOfFoundWords.add(resultWord);

                        }

                    }// headCoordinates

                }

            }

            List<Coordinate> headCoordinates = findHeadLettersCoordinates();
            List<Coordinate> allCoordinates = findAllLettersCoordinates();

            // STARTING ALL THREAD AUTOMATICALLY
            List<Thread> crosswordSpiders = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String direct : directions) {
                crosswordSpiders.add(new DirectionThread(direct, headCoordinates, allCoordinates));
            }

            // GATHERING THREAD RESULTS (listOfFoundWords)
            for (Thread thread : crosswordSpiders)
                thread.join();

            return listOfFoundWords;

        }

    }

    public List<Word> findSolutionForWord(String word) {

        CoordinateFabric coordinateFabric = new CoordinateFabric(word);
        List<Word> crosswordFoundWords = null;

        try {
            // STARTING OUR FABRIC
            crosswordFoundWords = coordinateFabric.startFabric();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        // RETURNING ALL FOUND WORDS
        return crosswordFoundWords;
    }

    public List<Word> doCrossword() {

        List<Word> detectedWords = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String textWord : words) {
            List<Word> listOfWords = findSolutionForWord(textWord);
            for (Word word : listOfWords)
                detectedWords.add(word);

        }

        return detectedWords;

    }

}

public static class Word {
    private String text;
    private int startX;
    private int startY;
    private int endX;
    private int endY;

    public Word(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public void setStartPoint(int i, int j) {
        startX = i;
        startY = j;
    }

    public void setEndPoint(int i, int j) {
        endX = i;
        endY = j;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s - (%d, %d) - (%d, %d)", text, startX, startY, endX, endY);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: В коде я оставил комментарии, где именно считаю я возникает проблемма.

Comment: Но не могу понять почему.

Answer (score 1):

Да вроде правильный ответ, вы ищите только home, программа правильно находит два home:
home - (5, 3) - (2, 3), home - (5, 3) - (2, 0).
"same" даже и не передается в detectAllWords. И если добавить, то будет результат:
home - (5, 3) - (2, 3) home - (5, 3) - (2, 0) same - (1, 1) - (4, 1)